# Grant table privileges to a user connecting from any host

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, authentication

I have a user account - let's call it 'wordpress' - that I need to allow to access a few catalog tables in another e-commerce database on the same server. I've configured the user with three host masks it's allowed to connect from: 'localhost', the IP address of the web server, and the hostname of the web server. No problems there.

The 'wordpress' user also has full access to its own database, granted via the Schema Privileges section in MySQL Workbench. Here, it shows the host is '%', which is what I want, since I don't want to manage three duplicate sets of privileges for the same user. If I look in mysql.db, I see these privileges, with '%' in the Host column.

So now I want to grant SELECT permission on a handful of tables in another database - let's call it 'store'. So I try this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON store.catalog TO 'wordpress'@'%';
```

And I get 'Can't find any matching row in the user table', for the obvious reason that '%' isn't a host mask I've explicitly allowed a connection from for this particular user. So what's the proper syntax to grant a table privilege to a user from any of its allowed host masks? How is MySQL Workbench getting away with it for schema privileges? I don't have to manually insert rows into mysql.tables_priv, do I?

**UPDATE**: To clarify, here's what the current user/grant tables look like. I've anonymized some names, obviously. Note that the host in the schema privilege table is '%', but there aren't any users with that host. How do I get MySQL to let me do that with schema object grants? Preferably without mucking around directly in mysql.tables_priv, but I'll do it if it comes down to it.

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'wordpress';
+-----------+-----------+
| user      | host      |
+-----------+-----------+
| wordpress | 10.0.0.22 |
| wordpress | webserver |
| wordpress | localhost |
+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT user, host, db, select_priv FROM mysql.db WHERE User = 'wordpress';
+-----------+------+----------------+-------------+
| user      | host | db             | select_priv |
+-----------+------+----------------+-------------+
| wordpress | %    | wordpress      | Y           |
| wordpress | %    | wordpress_test | Y           |
+-----------+------+----------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for wordpress@localhost                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '--' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'%';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'wordpress' on host '%'
```

Is MySQL Workbench doing something horribly undocumented with schema/object privileges? Just for kicks, I granted some table privileges to one of the specific user@host combinations, then updated mysql.tables_priv to change the host to '%'. After running FLUSH PRIVILEGES, it worked perfectly. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `GRANT SELECT ON store.catalog TO 'wordpress'@'%';`, mysqld wants to insert a row into the grant table `mysql.tables_priv`. Here is mysql.tables_priv:

```
mysql> show create table mysql.tables_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tables_priv
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tables_priv` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Table_name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Grantor` char(77) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Table_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','Delete','Create','Drop','Grant','References','Index','Alter','Create View','Show view','Trigger') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Column_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','References') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Table_name`),
  KEY `Grantor` (`Grantor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Table privileges'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since you want to insert a row into `mysql.table_priv` where user='wordpress' and host='%', there has to exist a row in `mysql.user` where user='wordpress' and host='%'.

You also mentioned that you are using MySQL Workbench. You must be using `'root'@'localhost'`. That would usually have all rights and a password.

If you want to just allow anonymous SELECT against that table, first run this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'%';
```

This will place `wordpress@'%'` into `mysql.user`. Afterwards, `GRANT SELECT ON store.catalog TO 'wordpress'@'%'` should run just fine.

You will have to see what other wordpress entries are in `mysql.user`. This should show what SQL GRANT commands you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON store.catalog TO ',userhost,';') GrantCommand
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT('''',user,'''@''',host,'''') userhost
    FROM mysql.user WHERE user='wordpress'
) A;
```

Comment: I actually only want the wordpress user to connect from those specific hosts. What's confusing is that the mysql.db table does have 'wordpress'@'%' entries for the schema privileges. MySQL Workbench created those, and I can't figure out what GRANT syntax allows that. I'd like to do the same for object privileges, if possible, so I don't need to maintain three identical sets of privileges.

Comment: You may have maintain identical wordpress users since (host,user) is primary key of mysql.user. That table is always double checked before checking entries into mysql.db. After all, wordpress@'%' is separate and distinct from worpress@localhost. By design, they do not share privileges. Check out my post on how MySQL User Authentication is loaded and maintained : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10897/877

Comment: See, that's the weird thing. It seems to be working perfectly fine like this. The wordpress user has full access to the wordpress database, despite the host being '%' in mysql.db, and individual host names in mysql.user. This is 5.5.11-log Win64, if that makes a difference.

Comment: When you connect to mysql as wordpress, run this command `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and tell me what you see

Comment: Shows it as `wordpress@localhost` for both, and I can fully access the wordpress database (but not other databases), based on the wordpress@% grant entry.

Comment: Run these : 1) `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'10.0.0.22';`, 2) `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'localhost';`, 3)  `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'webserver';`, 4) `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wordpress'@'%';`. (My guess is : the fourth query has to produce an error). Please post the output of each query in the question body without showing the password.

Comment: Alright, I stuck some more info in there. As expected, I get an error for the fourth query. It seems like MySQL internally supports grants that don't exactly match an existing host mask, but the various GRANT statements prevent you from doing it. And yet somehow MySQL Workbench gets away with it.

Comment: Do you have any anonymous users defined? Run this `SELECT * FROM mysql.user where user='';` Do any of the return rows have all Ys for the grant columns ???

Comment: Nope, no anonymous users. I get zero rows for that query.

Comment: Do you have any users with anonymous hosts defined? Run this `SELECT * FROM mysql.user where host='';` Do any of the return rows have all Ys for the grant columns ???

Comment: Negative on that as well. Zero rows returned.

Comment: MySQL Authentication must be check for grants in two phases. One against mysql.user and the other on mysql.tables_priv. They are apparently not being check with the same algorithm (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10897/877). It is like an exact search on mysql.user followed by a fuzzy search on mysql.tables_priv for permissions. Other than that, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me using the command line (not workbench):

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON foo.bar TO 'wordpress'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR wordpress@'%';
+------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for wordpress@%                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'%'          |
| GRANT SELECT ON `foo`.`bar` TO 'wordpress'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

I poked around and found this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59000). What version is your Workbench? It seems they have a fix, but not being a user of Workbench, I don't know their versioning (current version should be fixed).

Even if it's not, solution is to run it through command line!

Comment: +1 for going `CSI:Miami` on the bug report for Workbench

Comment: Actually, I am just doing it from the command line (well, through MySQL Query Browser, but same thing). I'll add some more details as to what the current user/grant tables look like. It's... strange.