# Why ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* gives access to all databases?

Tags: mysql

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10(quantal) and mysql-server-5.5.

When I execute:

```
drop user ''@'localhost';
create database `redmine`;
grant all on `redmine`.* to 'redmine'@'localhost';
```

User redmine@localhost can access not only redmine database, but also other databases.

How do I prevent him from accessing any database except redmine?

P.S.
I can't reproduce this on other distributions. What is a proper behaviour? Is this a bug?

**UPDATE1:**

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for redmine@localhost |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'redmine'@'localhost' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `redmine`.* TO 'redmine'@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| x |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

**The grants you gave on the `redmine` database have nothing to do with access to the test database**.

The problem is the way mysql was installed. It allows full access to the test database. It is not a bug. I wrote a past post (Question and Answer) on why anybody can access a test database and how to fix it:

- [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db) (Question)
- [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db/13363#13363) (Answer)

In essence, the problem is the table `mysql.db`. It contains entries that allow everyone and his grandmother to do anything in a test database or any database whose first five characters are `test_`. Removing those entries with `DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE LEFT(db,4)='test';` will immediately solve your particular problem.

I have other posts on how to thoroughly strip anonymous users from mysql.user and why

- [Cannot drop anonymous user from mysql.user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/cannot-drop-anonymous-user-from-mysql-user/4615#4615)
- [mysqladmin user account not secure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/mysqladmin-user-account-not-secure/17194#17194)
- [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)
- [Grant table privileges to a user connecting from any host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/grant-table-privileges-to-a-user-connecting-from-any-host/11051#11051)

Please read these carefully because my past answers will show you things like

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

This will break down the difference between how you logged in and how mysqld allowed you to login.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify by connecting using 'redmine'@'localhost' and see how many databases by executing this query:

> Show databases;

Also, you can execute another query to see exactly what are privileges given to 'redmine'@'localhost':

> show grants for 'redmine'@'localhost';

Comment: I did all that. Updating question for clarity.