# MySQL - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS on a new machine.  I logged into MySQL as root:

```
david@server1:~$ mysql -u root -p123
```

I created a new user called repl.  I left host blank, so the new user can may have access from any location.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'repl' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I checked the user table to verify the new user repl was properly created.

```
mysql> select host, user, password from mysql.user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | password                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root             | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| server1   | root             | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| ::1       | root             | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
| localhost |                  |                                           |
| server1   |                  |                                           |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *27F00A6BAAE5070BCEF92DF91805028725C30188 |
| %         | repl             | *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then exit, try to login as user repl, but access is denied.

```
david@server1:~$ mysql -u repl -p123
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'repl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
david@server1:~$ mysql -urepl -p123
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'repl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
david@server1:~$
```

Why is access denied?

Comment: I just tried dropping the user and creating with host localhost, and this worked.

CREATE USER 'repl'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';

But I do not want to restrict the user to some host, I would prefer to have any host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you could not login as `repl@'%'` has to do with [MySQL's user authentication protocol](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897). It does not cover patterns of users as one would believe.

Look at how you tried to logged in

```
mysql -u repl -p123
```

Since you did not specify an IP address, mysql assumes host is localhost and tries to connect via the socket file. This is why the error message says `Access denied for user 'repl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

One would think `repl@'%'` would allow `repl@localhost`. According to how [MySQL perform user authentication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897), that will simply never happen. Would doing this help ?

```
mysql -u repl -p123 -h127.0.0.1
```

Believe it or not, mysql would attempt `repl@localhost` again. Why? The mysql client sees `127.0.0.1` and tries the socket file again.

Try it like this:

```
mysql -u repl -p123 -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp
```

This would force the mysql client to user the TCP/IP protocol explicitly. It would then have no choice but to user `repl@'%'`.

Answer (score 5):

You should issue for localhost specific to it.

```
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
```

And try connecting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these two accounts, added by default.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | password                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost |                  |                                           |
| server1   |                  |                                           |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

A blank user name is a wildcard, so no matter what account you use, it matches this user if MySQL thinks you're connecting from localhost or your local server name (server1 in this case)... since they have no password, any password you try is wrong.  User authentication only tries the first match, so the user you created never gets noticed when your host is localhost (or your server name).

Delete these two from the `mysql`.`user` table and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Or, the [mysql_secure_installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) script can do this for you, although I tend to prefer doing things manually.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Database may not be configured yet just issue a no-arg call:

```
mysql <enter>

Server version: xxx

Copyright (c) xxx

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Mysql [(none)]>
```

If Mysql must be set a root password, you can use

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all fields in the connector are set up with the correct details

host = "localhost",
user = "CorrectUser",
passwd = "coRrectPasswd",
database = "CorreCTDB"

Check for upper and lowercase errors as well  - 1045 is not a Syntax error, but has to do with incorrect details in the connector

Answer (score -2):

This could be an issue with corruption of your mysql database. Tables inside mysql database like user table can get corrupt and may cause issued.

Please do a check on those

myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/mysql/ *.MYI

Usually while checking or fixing myisam tables we would like to take mysql down first. If this problem is still not solve please try this out aswell.

If they are corrupt then you can fix them using

myisamchk --silent --force --fast  /path/table-name.MYI

Thanks,

Masood