# error 1045(28000):anonymous user problem

Tags: mysql

I have removed anonymous users from mysql server but when one user trying to login from a specific host, current_user() still showing anonymous user.

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user\G  
*************************** 1. row ***************************  
user: a  
host: %  
*************************** 2. row ***************************  
user: root  
host: 127.0.0.1  
*************************** 3. row ***************************  
user: root  
host: ::1  
*************************** 4. row ***************************  
user: a  
host: hosta  
*************************** 5. row ***************************  
user: root  
host: hosta  
*************************** 7. row ***************************  
user: a  
host: localhost  
*************************** 8. row ***************************  
user: root  
host: localhost  
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)  


mysql> show grants for 'a'@'hosta';  
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Grants for a@hosta                                                                     
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'a'@'hosta' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxx'  
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I am giving correct password i am unable to login

```
mysql@hosta ==> mysql -ua -p -S /tmp/mysql.sock -h hosta  
Enter password:  
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'a'@'hosta' (using password: YES)
```

but when I am giving blank password, I am able to log in:

```
mysql@hosta ==> mysql -ua -p -S /tmp/mysql.sock -h hosta  
Enter password:  

mysql> select user(),current_user();  
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+  
| user()                                | current_user()        |  
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+  
| a@hosta                               | @hosta                |  
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I am running more than one port on server. So when i am trying to login like **mysql -ua -p -S /tmp/mysql.sock -h hosta** ,As there is no specific port mentioned , Its trying to login to 3306 instead of required port i.e 3311.As there are anonymous users in 3306 port, I am able to login with blank password and current_user is @hosta. So totally i am in a different server. So if you mention both socket and host ,It will use tcp protocol by default and does not use socket. And we should mention port number without fail , If you are using more than one instance on same server.

Comment: Still, what has priority, Socket or Host?  You can't do both at the same time, can you?

Comment: In my case it seems host has taken the priority when i have used both(socket and host) at a time

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are missing

- Connecting with user `a` via a socket is the same as connecting with user `a` via `localhost`.
- Connecting with a socket will not use TCP/IP

If you are going to explicitly using a hostname, you must use TCP/IP with port 3306 and no socket

```
mysql -ua -p -h hosta --protocol=tcp -P3306
```

I have discussed using `--protocol=tcp` in my earlier posts

- `Jul 16, 2015` : [mysql.sock not generated when starting MySQL server using XAMPP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/mysql-sock-not-generated-when-starting-mysql-server-using-xampp/107213#107213)
- `Jul 13, 2015` : [mysql restart issue after move database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106813/mysql-restart-issue-after-move-database/106816#106816)
- `Jul 11, 2013` : [Rare error lasts only a second "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (146)" 146=ECONNREFUSED](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46180/rare-error-lasts-only-a-second-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock/46184#46184)
- `Mar 28, 2013` : [MySQL - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user/38805#38805)

You need to delete blank users, blank hosts, and blank passwords from `mysql.user`

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE host = '';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE password = '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: there are no blank users,passwords and hosts in my users table.  not sure why current_user is @hosta even though there are no anonymous users.

Comment: i got what wrong i am doing. please see my answer and thanks for your valuable tips Rolando. i got some valuable info from your answer.