# mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, debian

I am troubleshooting a backup script (bash), and I have limited working knowledge of the current configuration since the last 3 predecessors did not leave any documentation.

I do know that my server is running MySQL Server 5.5.37 on a Debian machine. I'm manually testing the script and found `mysqldump` to be the problem. I realize there are very many posts on this same error message ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059823/mysqldump-error-1045-access-denied-despite-correct-passwords-etc), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744866/mysqldump-got-error-1045-access-denied), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)), but **none** of them have worked for me.

Running this command

```
mysqldump -uroot -p******** --all-databases > backup.all.sql 2> backup.all.err
```

produces the following error:

```
Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Here's a summary of what I've tried.

1. Verifying that root user can log in, and is being logged in correctly (ie. `USER(), CURRENT_USER();`).
2. I can log in to `mysql`with root user and supplying the `-p` flag. Yet if I supply the password as part of the cmd (ie. `mysql -uroot -p********`) I receive the same error as above.

   ```
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
   ```
3. Verified that every user has a password, there are no anonymous users, and root is in the users table with the normal hostnames (list below, shortened).

   ```
   +-------------+--------------+
   | user        | host         |
   +-------------+--------------+
   | root        | 127.0.0.1    |
   | root        | localhost    |
   +-------------+--------------+
   ```
4. I can run `mysqldump -p --all-databases` with limited success but will not work for my use case because I'd like the script to run automatically without the need for user interaction (eg. supplying the password before proceeding with the backup process).
5. Root user has all privileges on all dbs.

   ```
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | Grants for root@localhost                                         |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY   |
   | PASSWORD '*********' WITH GRANT OPTION                            |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```
6. Values in `/etc/mysql/my.conf` all seem to be pretty standard and are probably default. There are no additional `.conf` files.
7. Tried forcing a connection to localhost (which also forces use of the TCP protocol)

   ```
   mysql -h localhost -uroot -p********
   ```
8. Reviewed and tested each of the [Causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html) from the MySQL 5.5 docs.
9. Reset root password (not OS root user) using `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`
10. Flushed privileges, just in case, using `mysqladmin flush-privileges`
11. Ran `mysqlcheck --all-databases` in case mysql was corrupted. No errors were found.

Is there any reason why 'root'@'localhost' would still be denied when supplying the password for both `mysql` and `mysqldump`? Could both modules be ignoring the password I'm supplying and, if so, why? Lastly, is there anything else that I can try in order to allow me to log in by providing a password as part of the cmd?

Comment: if you add the user and password to a [client] section in ~/.my.cnf can you login without specifying user/password on the cli?

Comment: Yes, actually. Is it wise to put the root user's password in the `my.conf`? I mean, of course I'm doing the same thing by putting it in a shell script but at least I can manage permissions on that file.

Comment: Why use root? Create a backup user.

Comment: Also not /etc/my.cnf use /home/{user}/.my.cnf and manage the permissions on that file.

Comment: I was using root because that's what the script was using previously (and functioning) and I have no idea what permissions have been set on the other users. I figured root was easiest.

Comment: Are there any non-alphanumeric characters in the password?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes actually, a `$` symbol. I see now that that would be __very__ problematic when using it in a shell or script. I'll make some changes to it tomorrow and test.

Comment: I suspect that's exactly what it is. The answer I posted to the question in the comment above this one will give you several scenarios and workarounds, although it sounds like you already are familiar with shell behavior now that you're thinking about it.

Comment: I think the 'close as duplicate' votes were preemptive; I didn't even know what I was _really_ asking for, and anyone else in my situation might not be able to understand why this question was closed and linked to another (especially if they don't read all comments which are meant to be "temporary 'Post-It' notes"). @Michael-sqlbot you were right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In spite of the "please ask a new question" phrasing, above, I believe a question that's closed as a duplicate can be edited and reopened by vote or moderator action, if it turns out we were wrong. It isn't necessarily a permanent dismissal of your question and issue. It's true that your actual title and question don't make it obvious why it's a duplicate since you weren't clear on the nature of the problem when you asked, and the comments provide the only clear indication. However, the actual problem you experienced did turn out to be the same problem with the same solution. Happy to help.