# The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist

Tags: trigger, mariadb, permissions

I have a trigger defined as follow:

```
USE `veeva_bi`;
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veeva_bi.account_ai$$
USE `veeva_bi`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `veeva_bi`.`account_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `account` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    // do trigger stuff here
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run that query I got the trigger created as `root@localhost`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veeva_bi`.`account_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `account` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    // do trigger stuff here
END
```

But any time I try to run a PHP script, that connects to MariaDB as root user I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist' in /var/www/html/veeva_replicator/DB.php:158
```

Why is that? I have others triggers created on the same way and them did works but this one doesn't, any advice or help regarding this?

Comment: Do you have any user called `'root'@'%'`? In your question you have `'root'@'localhost'`, they're from diferent host `%` and `localhost`

Comment: @oNare I don't even know why trigger is called using `'root'@'%'` and not fom `'root'@'localhost'` as they should be called

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem when update a row in mysql.

I connect mysql use a diffrent user and password rather than root.

When I type "show triggers" in mysql, I found the triger use "root@%", this will cause this exception.

Answer (score 2):

Has to be a `PROXY` situation. As [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/proxy-users.html) says:

> When authentication to the MySQL server occurs by means of an
>   authentication plugin, the plugin may request that the connecting
>   (external) user be treated as a different user for privilege-checking
>   purposes. This enables the external user to be a proxy for the second
>   user; that is, to have the privileges of the second user. In other
>   words, the external user is a “proxy user” (a user who can impersonate
>   or become known as another user) and the second user is a “proxied
>   user” (a user whose identity can be taken on by a proxy user).

Run:

```
 GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You can refer to @RolandoMySQLDBA's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106444/mysql-grant-proxy-what-does-it-mean).

Comment: @rolandomysqldba says is better to delete that tables from MySQL and remove those privileges rather than run what you say, which one to follow?