# Why do I have different usernames from mysql.user and select user()?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, users

With 10.4.6-MariaDB on my Mac OS 10.14.5
Logged in as root I can see the list of users on my server with

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select Host,User from mysql.user;
+--------------+-----------+
| Host         | User      |
+--------------+-----------+
| localhost    |           |
| localhost    |           |
| localhost    | root      |
| localhost    | user_Name |
| PCName.local |           |
+--------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

but when logged in as user_Name and I check the current user

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user()
    -> ;
+-------------------------------+
| user()                        |
+-------------------------------+
| user_Name@localhost@localhost |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

That doesn't seem right to @localhost written twice.

So my question is why this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should run is this

Please run this query:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

What do these functions return ???

- [USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user/) reports how you attempted to authenticate in mysqld
- [CURRENT_USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/current_user/) reports how you were allowed to authenticate by mysqld

Please note that [CURRENT_USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/current_user/) should return something from `mysql.user`. You said that [USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user/) returns `user_Name@localhost@localhost`. If [CURRENT_USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/current_user/) comes back with the same response as [USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user/), then MariaDB has a bug.

Since [USER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user/) reports how you attempted to authenticate in mysqld, my guess would be that's probably how you typed it.

```
mysql -u user_Name@localhost
```

You should login to MariaDB like this

```
mysql -u user_Name -hlocalhost
```

Try it again and see. I discussed this before in this forum : [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)

Comment: Yes I logged in with the wrong login. Your second example needs a space after -h. thanks for explain user() and current_user()

Comment: @OrigamiEye it also works without the space `mysql -uuser_Name -hlocalhost`. Try it and see.

Comment: that's wild, it works.