# How to stop MySQL command from replacing hostname?

Tags: mysql

I have a server (MySQL 8.0.21) that replaces a host name or address with a name that does not exist as a host and thus does not connect. An example:

```
PS G:\workspace> mysql -u root -p -h geolaptop
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'gut-monitor' (using password: YES)
P
```

or

```
PS G:\workspace> mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.1.69
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'gut-monitor' (using password: YES)
PS G:\workspace>
```

I have set `skip-name-resolve` to `On`. I have queried `performance_schema.host_cache`:

```
mysql> use performance_schema;
Database changed
mysql> select * from host_cache;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So how does the host get changed, or better, how to make it stop?

Edit:
server's `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
...
127.0.0.1       match
127.0.0.1       diet
127.0.0.1       diet-fork
127.0.0.1       df2
127.0.0.1       pma
127.0.0.1       test
127.0.0.1       cr2
127.0.0.1       whodat

192.168.1.69    geolaptop
```

geolaptop`s host file:

```
...
127.0.0.1       castlerockhoa
127.0.0.1       hw_errors
192.168.1.76    gwb-10
192.168.1.76    diet-fork
192.168.1.76    gut-monitor
```

Comment: I'm confused. You have a "server", which apparently is different from `geolaptop`, and yet you're trying to connect to `geolaptop`? Shouldn't you be connecting to the server? Also, the hostname in the error message is that of the _client_, so I don't think the server is replacing anything.

Comment: I need to make clear that the command `mysql -u root -p -h geolaptop` is entered at a different computer than `geolaptop` named `gwb-10`. It is an attempt to connect to a remote system. If I'm at `geolaptop`, I can connect to  `gwb-10` without any problem. One should be able to connect to a remote MySQL server from the command line.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't make things any clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'gut-monitor' (using password: YES)
```

You are wondering "Where is `gut-monitoring` coming from" ?

That comes from MySQL. How ??? Plese run the following query:

```
SELECT
    USER() How_I_Am_Coming_Into_MySQL,
    CurrentUser() How_MySQL_Allowed_Me_To_Come_Into_MySQL
;
```

What are those functions ???

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in mysqld
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate by mysqld

What MySQL does is look for the user `'root'@'gut-monitor'` in the `mysql.user` table.

If it does not find that exact user, MySQL will look for other entries in `mysql.user` with the closest match to your username and host.

Once a match is found, then it checks your password.

Please see my Jan 18, 2012 post ([MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)) for the gory details on MySQL's authentication process.

Comment: If I understood your suggestion correctly, after entering at the command line `mysql -u root ...`, I then had to log in to mysql, again at the command line, which gave identical results for `USER()` & `CURRENT_USER()` as `root@::1`. If instead I do `mysql> select user  from mysql.user;` I get a list of users, none of which is `gut_monitor`.

Comment: In your case, `root@::` is the best match mysqld came up with when looking for credentials and coming up with a partial match. Your hostname is not being changed in any way.  mysqld sees you coming from `gut-monitor` so mysqld is looking for `root@gut-monitor`. If it cannot find it, it looks for other root users with less explicit hostname patterns as explained in my 2012 post (which comes from the MySQL Certification Book).

Comment: I discovered that I've been looking in all the wrong places. I can now accept your answer. Thank you very much.